# JSFiddle: What about data protection?

Tags: html, jsfiddle, data-protection

I'm currently working on a small tutorial on how to create webpages and embedded some code snippets using JSFiddle and iframes:

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="100"
  src="https://jsfiddle.net/klaraloreen/qnbrdjh6/11/embedded/html/dark"
  allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
  allowpaymentrequest frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Does anyone know if, and if yes, what kind of data are sent to JSFiddle as soon as my tutorial-page loads the iframes? Asking this, I mean user data like ip addresses. I've already read the docs of JSFiddle but couldn't find any information on that topic. I've also tried to get behind the network requests my page sends when loading, but I couldn't really figure out if data were sent.

It's relevant for me as I live in Germany where we have strict rules about data protection. As it's also quite critical to use Google Fonts, I'm not sure about JSFiddle.

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question; I'm still a newbie to web technologies and networking stuff.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: They can most definitely see the IP address, as that's a technical necessity to send any data back and forth at all. They will also see all the data that the browser sends in the HTTP request, which you can see in  the browser's developer tools' network inspector.

Comment: @deceze Thanks a million! That was exactly what I needed to know :)